# how to make only jumbotron background image dark

Tags: html, css

i have jumbotron with a background image , i put a
-webkit-filter: brightness(30%); on the background image, but this effect also affects all other images and text in the jumbotron, i am trying to make only the background image dull, and all other text and images bright, can anyone please assist me

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("apartment.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(30%);
}

img#sub {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2 class="section-title" style="word-wrap:break-word;"> <span id="section32"> </span> APARTMENTS</h2>
  <div align="center">
    <img id="divider" src="divide1.png">
  </div>


  <br></br>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Apartments</h2>

    <div align="center" class="container-fluid" id="ab">
      <div id="sub" class="column">
        <img id="sub" src="8.jpg" style="width:70%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>

      <div id="sub" class="column">
        <img id="sub" src="10.jpg" style="width:70%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

below is an image showing the dark effect all over
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNDIP.jpg)

Comment: Is it bootstrap you are using or regular CSS?

Comment: Could you just remove the filter from all elements contained in the jumbotron? Like `.jumbotron * { -webkit-filter: none; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about overlapping `background-image`

```
 background-image: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) ,
    url("Your URL");
```

---

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Tampa_FL_Sulphur_Springs_Tower_tall_pano01.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

.jumbotron img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
}

img#sub {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #efefef;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
}

.img-out {
  position: relative;
}

.img-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(45% - 24px);
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2 class="section-title" style="word-wrap:break-word;"> <span id="section32"> </span> APARTMENTS</h2>
  <div align="center">
    <img id="divider" src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/US/MAR2016/prestige-587705839_full.jpg">
  </div>


  <br></br>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Apartments</h2>

    <div align="center" class="container-fluid" id="ab">
      <div id="sub" class="column">
        <div class="img-out">
          <img id="sub" src="https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/images/lakeandballoon.jpg" style="width:70%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <p>TEXT 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="sub" class="column">
        <div class="img-out">
          <img id="sub" src="http://eskipaper.com/images/image-2.jpg" style="width:70%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <p>TEXT 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks, please one more thing, how do i add a text in the center of both images

Comment: i just did, but when i resize the page, the text leaves the box

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Instead of styling the background image container, I added a :before pseudo element to it, and set it to have a black overlay with an opacity of 50% using rgba.

```css
.jumbotron{background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/700");
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;

  background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
   }
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

img.subImg {
  padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
  }

.jumbotron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;     
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
}
```

```html
<section > 
    <h2 class="section-title" style="word-wrap:break-word;" >  <span 
    id="section32" > </span> APARTMENTS</h2>
    <div align="center">
        <img id="divider" src="divide1.png"  >
    </div>
    <div  class="jumbotron">
         <h2 style="text-align:center">Apartments</h2>
         <div  align="center" class="container-fluid" id="ab">
            <div id="sub1" class="column">
              <img class="subImg" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" 
    onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
            </div>

            <div id="sub2" class="column">
              <img class="subImg" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" 
    onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
background-image: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), url("apartment.jpg");
```

background-image can take multiple values.

Comment: This won't work, you will need to use `linear-gradient`. [**CHECK THIS**](https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/)